# How to enable/disable suggestions for character alternatives?

Tags: keyboard, preferences, accessibility, internationalization

I'm talking about the suggestions you (usually) get after you hold a key down for a few seconds. See image:

[image: OS X Character Suggestions]

For some reason they suddenly stopped working for me. I honestly don't recall changing some preference directly related to this.

I would to re-enable it again but I cannot find a way to do it. Does someone know how to accomplish this?